# How to call a method from InheritedWidget only once?

Tags: flutter, rxdart

*I'm developing with reactive components streams/observables with Rx_command, Rx_dart*

**Problem:**

- In my Flutter app I have inherited widget that can be called anywhere with:

  > FooProvider.of(context).foo.method1...
- I need to make a first call to the method when the UI loads at first time
- I can't use init.state because it's impossible
- I use *didchangedependencies* it works but..

  ... every time the ui reloads, the *didchangedependencies* is called and the method is executed once again.

I don't want it to be executed and I can't use init.state

How can execute the method **only once**?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType`, use `context.ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType`

```
final myInherited = context.ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType(MyInherited)?.widget;
```

This method is available inside `initState`