# How to handle navigation using stream from inheritedWidget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using an inherited Widget to access a Bloc with some long running task (e.g. search). 
I want to trigger the search on page 1 and continue to the next page when this is finished. Therefore I'm listening on a stream and wait for the result to happen and then navigate to the result page. 
Now, due to using an inherited widget to access the Bloc I can't access the bloc with `context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType()` during `initState()` and the exception as I read it, recommends doing this in `didChangeDependencies()`.

Doing so this results in some weird behavior as the more often I go back and forth, the more often the stream I access fires which would lead to the second page beeing pushed multiple times. And this increases with each back and forth interaction. I don't understand why the stream why this is happening. Any insights here are welcome. As a workaround I keep a local variable `_onSecondPage` holding the state to avoid pushing several times to the second Page.

I found now [How to call a method from InheritedWidget only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53022964/how-to-call-a-method-from-inheritedwidget-only-once) which helps in my case and I could access the inherited widget through `context.ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType()` and just listen to the stream and navigate to the second page directly from `initState()`. 
Then the stream behaves as I would expect, but the question is, does this have any other side effects, so I should rather get it working through listening on the stream in `didChangeDependencides()` ?

**Code examples**

My FirstPage widget listening in the `didChangeDependencies()` on the stream. Working, but I think I miss something. The more often i navigate from first to 2nd page, the second page would be pushed multiple times on the navigation stack if not keeping a local `_onSecondPage` variable.

```dart
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    debugPrint("counter: $_counter -Did change dependencies called");
    // This works the first time, after that going back and forth to the second screen is opened several times
    BlocProvider.of(context).bloc.finished.stream.listen((bool isFinished) {
       _handleRouting(isFinished);
    });
  }

  void _handleRouting(bool isFinished) async {
    if (isFinished && !_onSecondPage) {
      _onSecondPage = true;
      debugPrint("counter: $_counter -   finished: $isFinished : ${DateTime.now().toIso8601String()} => NAVIGATE TO OTHER PAGE");
      await Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
      );
      _onSecondPage = false;
    } else {
      debugPrint("counter: $_counter -    finished: $isFinished : ${DateTime.now().toIso8601String()} => not finished, nothing to do now");
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    debugPrint("counter: $_counter - disposing my homepage State");
    subscription?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            StreamBuilder(
              stream: BlocProvider.of(context).bloc.counter.stream,
              initialData: 0,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                _counter = snapshot.data;
                return Text(
                  "${snapshot.data}",
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

A simple Bloc faking some long running work

```dart
///Long Work Bloc
class LongWorkBloc {
  final BehaviorSubject<bool> startLongWork = BehaviorSubject<bool>();
  final BehaviorSubject<bool> finished = BehaviorSubject<bool>();

  int _counter = 0;
  final BehaviorSubject<int> counter = BehaviorSubject<int>();


  LongWorkBloc() {
    startLongWork.stream.listen((bool start) {
      if (start) {
        debugPrint("Start long running work");
        Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () => {}).then((Map<dynamic, dynamic> reslut) {
          _counter++;
          counter.sink.add(_counter);
          finished.sink.add(true);
          finished.sink.add(false);
        });
      }
    });
  }

  dispose() {
    startLongWork?.close();
    finished?.close();
    counter?.close();
  }
}
```

**Better working code**

If I however remove the code to access the inherited widget from `didChangeDependencies()` and listen to the stream in the `initState()` it seems to be working properly.

Here I get hold of the inherited widget holding the stream through `context.ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType()`

Is this ok to do so? Or what would be a flutter best practice in this case?

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //this works, but I don't know if this is good practice or has any side effects?
    BlocProvider p = context.ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType(BlocProvider)?.widget;
    if (p != null) {
      p.bloc.finished.stream.listen((bool isFinished) {
        _handleRouting(isFinished);
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I have not found any reason not to listen to BLoC state streams in `initState`. As long as you remember to `cancel` your subscription on `dispose`

If your `BlocProvider` is making proper use of `InheritedWidget` you should not have a problem getting your value inside of `initState`.

like So

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _counterBloc = BlocProvider.of(context);
    _subscription = _counterBloc.stateStream.listen((state) {
      if (state.total > 20) {
        Navigator.push(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return TestPush();
        }));
      }
    });
  }
```

Here is an example of a nice BlocProvider that should work in any case

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

import 'bloc_base.dart';

class BlocProvider<T extends BlocBase> extends StatefulWidget {
  final T bloc;
  final Widget child;

  BlocProvider({
    Key key,
    @required this.child,
    @required this.bloc,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BlocProviderState<T> createState() => _BlocProviderState<T>();

  static T of<T extends BlocBase>(BuildContext context) {
    final type = _typeOf<_BlocProviderInherited<T>>();
    _BlocProviderInherited<T> provider =
        context.ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType(type)?.widget;
    return provider?.bloc;
  }

  static Type _typeOf<T>() => T;
}

class _BlocProviderState<T extends BlocBase> extends State<BlocProvider<BlocBase>> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _BlocProviderInherited<T>(
      bloc: widget.bloc,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.bloc?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class _BlocProviderInherited<T> extends InheritedWidget {
  final T bloc;

  _BlocProviderInherited({
    Key key,
    @required Widget child,
    @required this.bloc,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedWidget oldWidget) => false;
}
```

... and finally the BLoC

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'bloc_base.dart';

abstract class CounterEventBase {
  final int amount;
  CounterEventBase({this.amount = 1});
}

class CounterIncrementEvent extends CounterEventBase {
  CounterIncrementEvent({amount = 1}) : super(amount: amount);
}

class CounterDecrementEvent extends CounterEventBase {
  CounterDecrementEvent({amount = 1}) : super(amount: amount);
}

class CounterState {
  final int total;
  CounterState(this.total);
}

class CounterBloc extends BlocBase {
  CounterState _state = CounterState(0);

  // Input Streams/Sinks
  final _eventInController = StreamController<CounterEventBase>();
  Sink<CounterEventBase> get events => _eventInController;
  Stream<CounterEventBase> get _eventStream => _eventInController.stream;

  // Output Streams/Sinks
  final _stateOutController = StreamController<CounterState>.broadcast();
  Sink<CounterState> get _states => _stateOutController;
  Stream<CounterState> get stateStream => _stateOutController.stream;

  // Subscriptions
  final List<StreamSubscription> _subscriptions = [];

  CounterBloc() {
    _subscriptions.add(_eventStream.listen(_handleEvent));
  }

  _handleEvent(CounterEventBase event) async {
    if (event is CounterIncrementEvent) {
      _state = (CounterState(_state.total + event.amount));
    } else if (event is CounterDecrementEvent) {
      _state = (CounterState(_state.total - event.amount));
    }
    _states.add(_state);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _eventInController.close();
    _stateOutController.close();
    _subscriptions.forEach((StreamSubscription sub) => sub.cancel());
  }
}
```